# LWC: Display HTML Content

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Aura components, we use  to display pre-formatted HTML. As per the document, there is no corresponding LWC component. Is there any way I can display HTML content stored in a metadata field as-is?

Comment: You can use [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation)?

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250666/using-unescape-html-in-lightning-web-component