# How to output HTML created in JavaScript in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, slds

Specifically I want to create some SLDS tooltip content that includes HTML such as `<br/>` in my JavaScript LWC controller.

There is [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification) and this answer [Using unescape HTML in lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250666/using-unescape-html-in-lightning-web-component) - use `lightning-formatted-rich-text` - but neither seem elegant to me.

Am I missing a better approach?

Comment: Define "elegant"? What are you hoping you'll find?

Comment: `lightning-unescaped-html` or Angular's `<div [innerHTML]=propertyHoldingHtml"></div>`.

Comment: What about `lwc:dom="manual"`, which would give you an element with more malleability?

Answer (score 3):

I side-stepped the problem by turning my tooltip data into an array of lines so the template could insert the markup, the most basic `<br/>` in this case:

```
<div class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom schedule-tooltip">
    <div class="slds-popover__body tooltip">
        <template for:each={tooltipLines} for:item="line">
            {line}<br key={line}/>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

which I suppose is the correct division of responsibilities between the template and the JavaScript. But not convenient for the developer.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood your question, but yes, that's probably the closest approximation. This is more a security feature than bug, but definitely rather annoying.

Comment: @sfdcfox Your answer is legitimate and answers the question; my particular problem didn't require arbitrary markup but others might. Perhaps the "best" answer is to write an LWC that does what `aura:unescapedHtml` does...

Comment: I concur. I'll see what I can come up with, not sure if the framework will like me for it.