# [LWC]: How to insert value as HTML not Text from Javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to dynamically populate HTML elements in my LWC. However it is showing as text, escaping the HTML characters.

I tried using `<lightning-formatted-rich-text>` but that is also not doing the trick for me.

Below is a sample of the code I've tried implementing.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper"
        <template for:each={tableColumnContentWrapper} for:item='contentColumn'>
            <div class="row" key={contentColumn.fieldName}>
                <div class="column">
                    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={contentColumn.stateHtml}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class MyClass extends LightningElement {
    @track tableColumnContentWrapper = [
        {
            fieldName: 'state',
            stateHtml: '<input type="text" placeholder="Your state" class="data-input"/>'
        }
    ];
}
```

This is what I see in the inspector:

[image: preview]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I do understand that this is not rich-text and as such it's not inserting an `<input />` element as I tested with `<h1></h1>` and that seems to be working alright.

I can modify the `innerHTML` but I wanted to try and see if there's a *cleaner* way of doing this first.

Comment: I asked the same question yesterday here [How to output HTML created in JavaScript in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297362/how-to-output-html-created-in-javascript-in-lwc) but with no compelling answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @KeithC I will keep an eye on your thread as well. For now I will just go with modifying the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically populate HTML in lightning web component you have to do below things:

**Define the element in LWC as :**

```
 <div class="elementHoldingHTMLContent" lwc:dom="manual">
 </div>
```

**Populate the HTML content from javascript as :**

```
this.template.querySelector('.elementHoldingHTMLContent').innerHTML = contentColumn.stateHtml;
```

Please note lwc:dom="manual" is important, that way you should be able to update innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

> If you set unsupported tags via JavaScript, those tags are removed and the text content is preserved. The supported HTML tags are: a, abbr, acronym, address, b, br, big, blockquote, caption, cite, code, col, colgroup, del, div, dl, dd, dt, em, font, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, i, img, ins, kbd, li, ol, mark, p, param, pre, q, s, samp, small, span, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, tt, u, ul, var, strike.

[Lightning Web Component
Formatted Rich Tex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation)

The input tag is not included in the list.
Plus you will need to replace the double quotes by single quotes in the html you are trying to render, or escape the double quotes by adding a backslash ( \" ) to every instance.

And in your template code, you are missing the closing tag for the wrapper div ;)